# How to set grid columns equally with another grid layout

Tags: html, css

I have a 2 types of layout using display grid.
[See Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eB6yh.jpg)

But i was wondering why the first columns are not equal in width?

Layout 1 first column width is: 239.40px

Layout 2 first column width is: 240.70px

how to set it equally using fr?

Here's my code

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 25px;
}

/* News Module 1 */
.grid-container--news1 {
  grid-template-columns: 2fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}

.grid-container--news1 .grid-item:nth-of-type(1) {
  grid-row: 1 / 4;
}

.grid-container--news1 .grid-item:nth-of-type(2) {
  grid-column: 2 / 4;
}

/* News Module 2 */
.grid-container--news2 {
  grid-template-columns: 1.3fr 1fr 1fr;
}

.grid-container--news2 .grid-item:nth-of-type(1) {
  grid-row: 1 / 3;
}

.grid-container--news2 .grid-item:nth-of-type(2) {
  grid-column: 2 / 4;
}

.grid-item {
  background: steelblue;
  color:
```

```html
<div class="row gx-3 gx-md-4">
        <div class="col-12 mb-3">
          <h3>News Module 1</h3>
          <div class="grid-container grid-container--news1">
            <?php for ($i=1; $i < 7; $i++): ?>
            <div class="grid-item"><?php echo $i; ?></div>
            <?php endfor; ?>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-12">
          <h3>News Module 2</h3>
          <div class="grid-container grid-container--news2">
            <?php for ($i=1; $i < 5; $i++): ?>
            <div class="grid-item"><?php echo $i; ?></div>
            <?php endfor; ?>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Please add your html code too

Comment: It is a rounding issue that is caused by the different ammounts of gaps.

Comment: do you use `* {box-sizing:border-box}` ? If not that may be the problem (paddng or borders)

Comment: i update my post. html code included

Comment: im using `* {box-sizing:border-box}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you'll manage to set it equally using fr.

There will be rounding errors and with your gap sizes being specified in absolute px units regardless of the value of 1vw the two layouts aren't going to be left with the same amount of free space.

You could however set the first column to a percentage and they should then come out the same on both layouts.

Alternatively you can do a calculation to decide the width you want in terms of the width of the container less the gaps.

Looking at the first grid we've got:

2fr + 3*25px +3fr = 100%

So the width of the first column can be calculated by CSS as

```
  calc((100% - 75px) * 2 / 5)
```

You can specify that for the width of the first column for both layouts and then the remaining fr settings as you have now.

Comment: This actually works. Can you explain in detail on how you come up with that calculation? 

That 100% - 75px part (what is that 75px?)

and * 2 / 5

Comment: If you look at the equation it’s calculating for the first set up. There are 3 gaps of 25px each and 5fr and in total they come to 100% of the parent width. The left hand column you have specified as 2fr and from the equation we can work out what that is.

Answer (score 1):

easy way to get around is to use "%" to set the width of the first column rather than "fr".

Rather than using:

```
.grid-container--news1 {
  grid-template-columns: 2fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}

/* News Module 2 */
.grid-container--news2 {
  grid-template-columns: 1.3fr 1fr 1fr;
}
```

you can use:

```
.grid-container--news1 {
  grid-template-columns: 40% 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}

/* News Module 2 */
.grid-container--news2 {
  grid-template-columns: 40% 1fr 1fr;
}
```